# Is there a possible way to make Android studio format the code?

Tags: android, android-studio, formatting

Is there a possible way to make Android studio format the code automatically without pressing CTRL +ALT+L?

I mean is this option available like the automatic import?

Thank you

Answer (score 13):

There is no way to do that automatically.
But you can create a macro that will do it for you.

For example, I changed the short-cut use to save CTRL+S by a macro that format the code then save. It's very usefull when you save a lot.

To do so :

- Go in Edit/Macro/Start Macro Recording
- Press CTRL+ALT+L then CTRL+S
- Edit/Macro/Stop Macro Recording
- Then change the short-cut of save by your macro in the Settings

Hope that help.

Comment: Hello to change the shortcut to a macro : go to Settings/KeyMap then search for your macro, right click on it and click on add Keyboard Shortcut.